Why does 'const' hinder template resolution when inside a 'shared_ptr'?
Given a shared_ptr to a non-template class, I regularly pass such a variable to methods expecting shared_ptr<const ...>, like so (https://godbolt.org/z/47eEPr5d1):
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class NotTemplated
{
public:
    NotTemplated( const int& t ) : val(t) {}
    int val;
};

int Foo(std::shared_ptr<const NotTemplated> p) 
{ 
   return p->val;
}

int main()
{
    auto pNotTemplated = std::make_shared<NotTemplated>( 6 );
    std::cout << Foo( pNotTemplated ) << "\n";

    return 0;
}

And the compiler is smart enough to convert shared_ptr<NonTemplated> to shared_ptr<const NonTemplated>
However, consider the case when the class is templated (https://godbolt.org/z/devd3G818):
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class Templated
{
public:
    Templated( const T& t ) : val(t) {}
    T val;
};

template <typename T>
T Foo(std::shared_ptr<const Templated<T>> p) 
{ 
   return p->val;
}

//Not adding this overload fails compilation:
//template <typename T>
//T Foo(std::shared_ptr<Templated<T>> p) 
//{ 
//   return p->val;
//}

int main()
{
    auto pTemplated = std::make_shared<Templated<int>>( 5 );
    std::cout << Foo( pTemplated ) << "\n";

    return 0;
}

The commented function differs from the existing one only by the constness of the type inside the shared_ptr argument.  But without it, compiler fails with the following errors:
<source>(28): error C2672: 'Foo': no matching overloaded function found
<source>(28): error C2784: 'T Foo(std::shared_ptr<const Templated<T>>)': could not deduce template argument for 'std::shared_ptr<const Templated<T>>' from 'std::shared_ptr<Templated<int>>'

So:

Passing a non-const param to a function expecting a const is obviously known to be ok.
Passing a smart-pointer-to-non-const to function expecting smart-pointer-to-const is also ok.

Why is it that template resolution fails here??
[If it makes any difference, I'm using C++ 17, on MSVC (latest version of Visual Studio 2019]
Edit: The linked duplicate question doesn't fully answer my question though. As the first godbolt link clearly shows, shared_ptr<A> does implicitly get converted to shared_ptr<A const>. I see this happening only when A itself is a template, so it is something more complicated/delicate than that...

The problem is type deduction doesn't consider implicit conversion and failed. Specifying template argument like Foo<int>( pTemplated ) should work.

BTW, Foo doesn't play with ownership, so you might use const Templated<T>* or const Templated<T>& instead.

Regarding your edit, the duplicate target is about templates. The question is admittedly not great, because it lacks a MRE, but take a look at the answer. (I've added another duplicate target that is a bit clearer. It's technically about tr::shared_ptr but that's not relevant here).
